# Find a Sunday between two dates in Javascript

Tags: javascript, date

In the United States, the Christian feast of Epiphany occurs on the Sunday between January 2 and January 8 (inclusive). I'm trying to use Javascript to find what date it falls on. It seems like it should work, but I'm getting nothing:

```js
var startDate = new Date(2018,0,2);
var endDate = new Date(2018,0,8);
var epiphanyUS = new Date();

while (startDate < endDate){
  if (startdate.getDay() === 0){
    epiphanyUS = startdate;
  }
  startDate.setDate(startDate.getDate() + 1);
}
console.log("Epiphany is" + epiphanyUS.format("MM-DD-YYYY"));
```

Comment: For starters, this is a typo: `startdate` and `epiphanyUS` should be declared with the `var` keyword or the like.

Comment: and you don't use `return` statements inside the loops.

Comment: Where are you returning `epiphanyUS` from? And what are you returning it for? You’re already setting it inside the `if` statement. Do you see the error in the snippet?

Comment: @kiddorails - Thanks, I didn't catch that.

Comment: Now you’ve only got to fix the typo `startdate` vs. `startDate` as pointed out in the first comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed a couple of typos you had and defined all of your variables explicitly. I think your while loop logic could have been cleaner as well. I don't know if you are using an external JS library (moment?), but .format isn't a method I'm familiar with. Lastly, I added a year variable so you can quickly amend it to find epiphany in any other year.

```js
var year = 2018;
var startDate = new Date(year,0,2);
var endDate = new Date(year,0,8);
var epiphanyUS;

while (startDate <= endDate) {
    if (startDate.getDay() === 0) {
        epiphanyUS = startDate;
        break;
    } else {
        startDate.setDate(startDate.getDate() + 1);
    }
}

console.log("Epiphany is " + epiphanyUS.toDateString());
```

Comment: Since the OP says the dates are inclusive, the condition should be `startDate <= endDate` per Brett's answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can also wrap your logic in a function if you'd rather use return statements.

```js
var startDate = new Date(2018,0,2);
var endDate = new Date(2018,0,8);

function getEpiphanyUS (startDate, endDate) {

  while (startDate <= endDate) {
    if (startDate.getDay() === 0){
      return startDate
    }
    startDate.setDate(startDate.getDate() + 1);
  }

}

var epiphanyUS = getEpiphanyUS (startDate, endDate)
console.log("Epiphany is " + epiphanyUS.toDateString());
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `break` when you find the match. It will enable you to get out the loop.

```js
var startDate = new Date(2018,0,2);
var endDate = new Date(2018,0,8); 
var epiphanyUS; // you should also define the variable you intend to use later.
    
while (startDate <= endDate){ // inclusive of endDate
  if (startDate.getDay() === 0){
    epiphanyUS = startDate; // fix the typo. It's startDate, not startdate
    break; // break when match is found.
  }
  startDate.setDate(startDate.getDate() + 1);
}
// check for presence and do stuff accordingly, like console.log
if(epiphanyUS) console.log("Epiphany is " + epiphanyUS);
```

Comment: Also, the `<` condition should be `<=` as the dates are inclusive (or the end date should be changed to 9 January). You could also break out of the loop using `while (startDate <= endDate && typeof epiphanyUS == 'undefined')` or `!epiphanyUS` or similar.

Comment: @RobG - _return statement must not be used_ was referring to the original code of OP where he was using return statement inside the conditional (with no enclosing function), please refer the edit.

Comment: Edited my comment. Your comment on the return statement is now redundant so you should probably edit the answer. I was just pointing out that there are other ways to break out of the loop than *break*. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

```js
var startDate = new Date(2018,0,2);
var endDate = new Date(2018,0,8);
var epiphanyUS;
    
while (startDate < endDate){
  if (startDate.getDay() === 0){
    epiphanyUS = startDate;
  }
  startDate.setDate(startDate.getDate() + 1);
}
function format(date) {
  var year = date.getFullYear();

  var month = (1 + date.getMonth()).toString();
  month = month.length > 1 ? month : '0' + month;

  var day = date.getDate().toString();
  day = day.length > 1 ? day : '0' + day;
  
  return month + '/' + day + '/' + year;
}
console.log("Epiphany is " + format(epiphanyUS));
```

Watch out for capitalization typos like startDate and startdate.

Answer (score 1):

You can greatly simplify the code if you reduce the logic to return the first Sunday on or after 2 January for a particular year:

```js
/* @param {number} year - year to get epiphany for. Defaults to current year
** @returns {Date} First Sunday on or after 2 January for given year
*/
function getEpiphanyUS(year = new Date().getFullYear()) {
  var d = new Date(year, 0, 2);
  d.setDate(d.getDate() + ((7 - d.getDay()) % 7));
  return d;
}

// Test 2018 + next 9 years
for (var i=0; i<10; i++) {
  console.log(getEpiphanyUS(2018 + i).toString());
}
```